# unhiding a div tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/jquery01.html

Clicking the button on that page should unhide the "hello, world!" div tag shouldn't it?  When I click it I get a `$("#demo").style is undefined` error.

Comment: What should happen when you click the button again when the div is already visible?

Comment: there are **nine** answers but till no one selected.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#button").click(function () {
      $("#div").hide();
});
$("#button").click(function () {
   $("#div").show(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this , the simplest one ..

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#demo').toggle()" value="clicking me should unhide a div tag">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$('#demo').show(); // to display
```

or

```
$('#demo').hide(); // to hide the div
```

Answer (score 0):

try [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
$("#demo").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`hide()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hide)

```
$("#demo").hide()
```

or

```
$("#demo").hide()
```

or even the [`toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) to toggle visibility:

```
$("#demo").toggle()
```

Integrated in your example:

```
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>

        <body>
            <div>
                <input type="button" onclick="javascript:$('#demo').show();" value="clicking me should unhide a div tag">
            </div>
            <div id="demo" style="display: none">hello, world!</div>
        </body>

</html>
```

Example from jQuery [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aBasic_Show_and_Hide):

```
<h1 class="firstHeading" style="display: block;">Tutorials:Basic Show and Hide</h1>
<div class="examples">
    <input id="hideh1" type="submit" value="Hide site tile" name="hideh1">
    <input id="showh1" type="submit" value="Show site title" name="showh1">
    <input id="toggleh1" type="submit" value="Toggle site title" name="toggleh1">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#hideh1').click(function () {
                $('div.showhide,h1').hide();
            });
            $('#showh1').click(function () {
                $('div.showhide,h1').show();
            });
            $('#toggleh1').click(function () {
                $('div.showhide,h1').toggle();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
      $("#demo").show();
  });
});
```

or

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#demo").style` is not a jQuery function

You should either use `$("#demo").css("display","block")` property or use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show) or [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) functions

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access properties of jQuery objects by . (dot) (They are not javascript objects)

You this,

```
$('#demo').css({'display':'none'})
```

Or you can use `$('#demo').hide();`   (Its a shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

[`jQuery.hide()` is **very** slow](http://jsperf.com/jquery-dumb-hide).

Use the following instead:

```
document.getElementById('demo').style.display = 'none'
```

This is where you heard of the `style` property. This property works on DOM objects. jQuery objects are not DOM objects.